# joining two dataframe on date column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

How can I join two dataframe  on date column with same and different frequencies as in the below example.

**scenario 1**

```
fast = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.to_datetime(['2018-01', '2018-02', '2018-03',
                            '2018-04', '2018-05', '2018-06']),
    'store': ['A'] * 3 + ['B'] * 3,
    'sales': [3000, 2000, 1800, 1700, 1500, 1600]})

slow = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.to_datetime(['2018-01', '2018-03', '2018-06']),
    'temp': [45, 55, 70]})

alligned_left_fast = ?

alligned_left_slow = ?
```

**same frequency, scenario 2**

```
unaligned_df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.to_datetime(['2018-01', '2018-02', '2018-03',
                            '2018-04', '2018-05', '2018-06']),
    'store': ['A'] * 3 + ['B'] * 3,
    'sales': [3000, 2000, 1800, 1700, 1500, 1600]})

unaligned_df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.to_datetime(['2018-02-11', periods=6, freq='30D']),
    'temp': [105, 95, 87]})
Unaligned_merged_left_date_index=?
```

**different frequency, scenario 3**

```
unaligned_fast_diff_freq = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.to_datetime(['2018-01-12', '2018-02-10', '2018-02-16',
                            '2018-04-28', '2018-04-29', '2018-06-11']),
    'store': ['A'] * 3 + ['B'] * 3,
    'sales': [3000, 2000, 1800, 1700, 1500, 1600]})

unaligned_slow_diff_freq = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.to_datetime(['2018-04', '2018-05', '2018-01', '2018-06']),
    'sales': [2700, 2500, 2600, 3300]})

unaligned_fast_slow= ?
```

Comment: Do you want the slow df to be joined to every element in the fast df with the same month?

Comment: Yes, I want to join slow df to every element in the  fast df with the same month, taking date as index @RCA

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.merge_asof` with `direction` parameter.

```
pd.merge_asof(fast,slow, on='date', direction='backward')
```

Output:

```
        date store  sales  temp
0 2018-01-01     A   3000    45
1 2018-02-01     A   2000    45
2 2018-03-01     A   1800    55
3 2018-04-01     B   1700    55
4 2018-05-01     B   1500    55
5 2018-06-01     B   1600    70
```

Comment: How do I Print frequency or show the range in the date column?
Ex:         date                       store  sales  temp
    2018/01/01 - 2108/01/31     A   3000    45

Comment: How do I know the frequency?  Is that a week, a month or year?

Comment: yes, I have the same question.
Is their a way I can check/specify the frequency?